# Как удалить открывающий и закрывающий тег  из таблицы?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как удалить открывающий и закрывающий тег <tr> из таблицы, где найдено определенное слово - `/<tr>.*Die prozentualen Provisionssätze.*</tr>/`  не сработало ((

Comment: Используйте минимальную квантификацию **`.*?`** вместо максимальной **`.*`**

Answer (score 1):

Задача делится на 2 этапа:
1. Найти совпадение.
2. Заменить выражение на нужное (в данном случае удалив теги)

Решается в зависимости от диалекта регулярных выражений и способа их обработки. В perl задачу можно решить, используя исходное регулярное выражение из вопроса:

```
s/<tr>(.*слово.*)<\/tr>/$1/g
```

в переменную $1 сохранится выражение в круглых скобках, которым заменяется исходный совпавший текст. s/ - указывает на необходимость заменить исходный текст, /g - модификатор глобального поиска

Comment: Используйте минимальную квантификацию вместо максимальной. Ваше выражение удалит все от первого открывающего тэга до последнего закрывающего. Поверьте на тексте:  

    <tr> random text</tr>
    <tr>слово</tr>
    <tr>слово</tr>
    <tr> random text</tr>

Comment: А если это мне нужно решить на php?